# How to send ctrl+z

Tags: c#, c++, string

How do I convert <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to a string?

I am sending this as an AT COMMAND to an attached device to this computer.

Basically, I just to put some chars in a string and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> in that string as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following will work for you

```
serialPort1.Write("Test message from coded program" + (char)26);
```

also try may work for you

```
serialPort1.Write("Test message from coded program");
   SendKeys.Send("^(z)");
```

also check : http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/48708-sending-ctrl-z-through-serial/

Answer (score 9):

You can embed any Unicode character with the `\u` escape:

```
"this ends with ctrl-z \u001A"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
buffer[0] = 26; // ^Z
modemPort.Write(buffer, offset:0, count:1);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's clear from other responses that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> has ASCII code 26; in general <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+[letter] combinations have ASCII code equal to 1+[letter]-'A' i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+A has ASCII code 1 (\x01 or \u0001), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+B has ASCII code 2, etc.

Answer (score 1):

When sending characters to a device, translation from the internal string representation is needed. This is known as [`Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) - an encoder translates the string into a byte array.

Consulting the [Unicode Character Name Index](http://www.unicode.org/charts/charindex.html), we find the `SUBSTITUTE - 0x001A` character in the `C0 Controls and Basic Latin` (ASCII Punctuation) section.
To add a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> to an internal C# string,
add a [unicode character escape sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) (`\u001a`) code.

```
String ctrlz = "\u001a";
String atcmd = "AT C5\u001a";
```

Any encoding used for translation before output to the device
(for example output using [`StringWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter.aspx)), will translate this to ASCII <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>.